# "in every respect" vs "in every aspect"

Tags: word-choice

There is a quote from a local translation bureau website:

> A translation shall be excellent *in every respect*: style, and formatting, and words, and meaning.

Is the use of 'in every respect' appropriate in this context?

I feel that 'style, formatting, words, and meaning' are aspects (or attributes) of a translation. Can we call them 'respects'?

Comment: Both make sense. *In every respect* is more idiomatic.

Comment: What made you suspect 'in every respect' might be inappropriate?

Answer (score 4):

I can't see (or hear) anything wrong with:

> Every aspect of a translation shall be excellent: its style,
>   formatting, words, and meaning.

Here, the 'feature' sense of *aspect* is being used.

So I don't see how one can argue on semantic grounds that the following is wrong:

> A translation shall be excellent in (its) every aspect: style,
>   formatting, words, and meaning.

Syntactically, it seems fine too.

Which only leaves us with concerns about style.

And I'd agree that the second alternative here sounds decidedly unnatural - and I'd also agree with Barrie that it's because '[t]he usual collocations are *in every respect*, but ***from*** every aspect ('from' referencing the transferred literal, *viewpoint*, sense of aspect - *from every aspect*, transference of *from every viewpoint*). The first offering here avoids the unusual prepositional usage by avoiding use of the preposition.

Answer (score 3):

*Respect* here has the meaning ‘a particular, a point, a detail’. *Aspect* would not be appropriate. It means, among many other things, ‘the appearance presented by an object to the eye’.

Comment: I'm bit confused. I see following definitions for **aspect** on dictionary.com: 2) _nature; quality; character_ 5) _part; feature; phase_ . For me they seem to be close to my interpretation of word **aspect**. Can we say "from the aspect of style" or "from the aspect of grammar"?

Comment: Yes, you can in the appropriate context, but, in your example, _respect_ is what is needed. I'll say in passing that the whole style is a little strange.

Comment: Well, I still don't understand how to choose between 'in every aspect' and 'in every respect'. I see a lot of usage of these phrases in google and with **aspect** it is used twice as often as with **respect**.

Comment: You can't apply logic to language and always expect to be right.  There are 1000 examples of words used incorrectly according to the dictionary in every day english.  Regardless of the what a dictionary will tell you, people use whatever they grew up with.  With your example "every respect" is appropriate and preferred all over the U.S.

Comment: @TurtlePowered Can you provide some examples where 'in every aspect' is appropriate to use? Or better, if you could modify sentence above so it would be possible to see difference in context.

Comment: The usual collacations are _in every respect_, but _from every aspect_.

Comment: @AlexD "TurtlePowered's answer was correct in every aspect.  There is no denying that he is as intelligent as he is handsome."  :)

Comment: That should have been _collocations_.

Comment: Never mock Turtle.

Comment: @BarrieEngland I checked online Oxford Collocation Dictionary and it lists following for **aspect**: _PREP. from the … ~ This scheme is very good from the social aspect. | ~ to the positive aspects to retirement; PHRASES all aspects of sth, (in) every aspect (of sth) The service was excellent in every aspect._

Answer (score 1):

The definitions you are using for aspect are subtly different from what we are talking about. Very often, a slight shade of meaning makes a big difference to how we understand something. Unless you grasp the slight variance in meaning, you won't grasp the usages in question. Let me explain by using a single example. You point out that one meaning of "aspect" includes the word "character." When I read your comments closely, it appears to me that you are confusing this meaning with "characteristic," which is what "style, formatting," and so on, actually are. They are characteristics of the work, whereas "character" is the overall defining substance of something. The other two words in this definition, "nature" and "quality," are meant here to mean exactly that: the entire identifiable "thingness" of whatever you are talking about.

If we then take this meaning of "aspect" ("nature, quality, character") and apply it *correctly* to your original example, we might comment that "the outstanding aspect of the translation was that it was powerful and accurate."

Keep in mind, then, that aspect tends to refer to the entire object.

If we look at your other noted definition of "aspect," we see "part, feature, phase." Again, the subtlety of interpretation of the meaning here is essential. Once again, these words are referring to something more allied with overall perceived identifications of the thing. Following are some examples. For *feature*: "One aspect (feature) of his work was its cleanliness." For *phase*: "In its later aspect (phase), the caterpillar is a butterfly." The important differentiation to make here, going back to your example, is that "aspect" would be referring to some perception of the finished product or entity on the part of an observer, whereas the characteristics you mention ("style" and so on) are really intended to be seen in this context as formative elements in the process of creating the translation.

For these reasons, "in every respect" is the correct usage, and importantly, it is the standard, expected, and well-understood phrase in this context. "In every aspect" is not used in this way; it would mean "in every perceived characteristic." (Think finished product, not creative elements.)

Comment: But "character" also means one of the overall thing's features, not just the complete work.

Answer (score 0):

"in every aspect" communicates closer down the spectrum of technicalities, i.e. it means something more akin to "all elements of the thing."

"in every respect" communicates closer down the spectrum of interpretations, i.e. it means something more akin to "all things related to the thing (in question)."

And if I'm wrong then that's fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).